# What is the purpose of GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT and GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT?

Tags: opengl

As an OpenGL beginner I would like to know what do they do and why these are required. For instance in the call

```
 glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT` and `GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT` aren't functions, they're constants.  You use them to tell `glClear()` which buffers you want it to clear - in your example, the depth buffer and the "buffers currently enabled for color writing".  You can also pass `GL_ACCUM_BUFFER_BIT` to clear the accumulation buffer and/or `GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT` to clear the stencil buffer.

The actual values of the constants shouldn't matter to you when using the library - the important implementation detail is that the binary representations for each constant don't overlap with each other.  It's that characteristic that lets you pass the bitwise OR of multiple constants to a single call to `glClear()`.

Check out the [`glClear()` documention](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glClear.xml) for more details.

Comment: I'm asking about those constants why we use them I want more Information about them please!!

Comment: @Mohamed - what do you mean more information?  The documentation has everything you need to know.  Do you have a more specific question?

Comment: the documentations tells me GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT
                        Indicates the buffers currently enabled for color
                        writing.
                    GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT
                        Indicates the depth buffer.

Comment: and I want more about those constants please!! :)

Comment: There isn't any more information about them... I guess you could look in `gl.h`.  On my machine `GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT` is `0x00004000` and `GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT` is `0x00000100`.  What else is there to know about?

Comment: @Carl Norum: The numeric values of those OpenGL tokens (constants) are written down in the specification. @Mohamed Amged: The value passed to glClear is evaluated within the OpenGL driver by some code similar to this: glClearOfTheDriver(GLbitfield mask){ if(mask & GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT) clear_the_color_buffer; if(mask & GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT) clear_the_depth_buffer; ... }; there's really nothing more to this. Those tokens passable to glClear are orthogonal (bit) vectors (look up orthogonal vectors on Wikipedia to understand what this means).

Comment: I have got a question.
I was trying to run an OpenGL code, it didn't have GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT cleared in glClear(), because of which I couldn't render my scene. I added this bit, and the scene was rendered.

Why is it necessary to use this clear bit? I may know the exact reason for this, to clear the depth buffers values used by GPU prevoiously, but i just want to confirm.

Comment: @2am, you should probably post a question, not a comment.

Comment: @CarlNorum, Got a prefect explanation here. Cheers. [Why do we clear GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19469194/why-do-we-have-to-clear-depth-buffer-in-opengl-during-rendering/19469291#19469291)

Comment: @2am Thank you, that's what I was expecting from here. Not "check documentation".

Answer (score 4):

A call to glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT) clears the OpenGL color and depth buffers (or any other buffer or combination of buffers). OpenGL being a state machine, it is good practice to start each frame with a clean slate.

Answer (score 1):

I stumble upon this question while reading about this and thought to add some details for anyone confused. I see these two variables are constant represent options in bit values.

The glClear() method needs to know what type of buffer to clear. However, there are many buffers such as color and depth buffers and others (https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glClear.xml).

By using bits to represent options it become easier to set multiple options by performing an OR operation.

For more details check out this "Bit Manipulation" tutorial, namely "When are bit flags most useful?" section at : https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/bit-manipulation-with-bitwise-operators-and-bit-masks/