# glClear [ GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT and GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT ]

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics

I'm learning these tutorials for `OpenGL` in http://LearnOpenGL.com and I faced with this function `glClear` ( [here](https://learnopengl.com/#!Getting-started/Hello-Window) at the Rendering title ). Scince I'm still learning Eng as well I have trouble with the world " clear " in this function. (1) What does it mean to clear a buffer bit?

(2) what's the meaning of the word " clear " in these three values below?

```
GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT and GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5479951/what-is-the-purpose-of-gl-color-buffer-bit-and-gl-depth-buffer-bit

Answer (score 2):

From here: https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glClear.xml

> `glClear` sets the bitplane area of the window to values previously
>   selected by `glClearColor`, `glClearIndex`, `glClearDepth`, `glClearStencil`,
>   and `glClearAccum`

So it simply *assigns* default values to buffer bits.